# Oracle SQL Getting error missing right parenthesis with my query and cannot figure out why

Tags: sql, oracle

SELECT SUBSTR(first_name,1 1)||' '|last_name,
"Employee Name", salary "Salary",
DEC(commission_pct NULL, 'No', 'Yes')'Commission'
FROM employees;

Trying to get a query for first initial last name  the salary and yes or no if they have a commission

Comment: I've never seen the `DEC` function before, but right away I can see that you are using `'Commission'` in single quotes as an alias.  It should be double quotes, I think, or no quotes at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want a query like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1) || ' ' || last_name as Employee_Name, 
       salary,
       (CASE WHEN commission_pct IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END) as Commission
FROM employees e;
```

Your query has numerous typographical errors.

Comment: Thank you! I am still new to SQL and playing around with tables and queries